# What are other symbols like → that can be used in StackExchange sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, stack-exchange

What are other symbols like → that can be used on StackExchange sites? Where is a list of all of these stackExchange symbols or can somewhere share that list here? Can symbols be added to the StackExchange post repository.

Comment: Stack Exchange posts support Unicode; the list is the full Unicode specification. Here, have a snowman while you read: ☃

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unicode characters that are not specific to the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: `var s = ""; for (var i = 0xff; i < 0xfffff; i++) s += String.fromCharCode(i); s`. This and more!

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_sl99D2a18.

Comment: @Rosinante  Thanks now I know that it takes 33 minutes to show all displayable characters in the unicode range 0 - 65536 (49571 characters) at one character per frame.

Answer (score 5):

Please visit http://www.unicode.org to sip from the flood of possible Unicode characters.

Comment: [Wikipedia List_of_Unicode_characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) is hard to search... is there another site where I can search for and copy the Unicode directly for pasting into a StackExchange post?

Comment: fileformat.org is searchable by character name.

Comment: If i got fileformat and wnat this [thumbs up unicode image](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm) then how do I copy or use it in a StackExchange post?

Comment: @javaPlease42: Scroll down. You can also try http://codepoints.net/.